# Where do I use the fact that $V$ is closed in $X$ in the following proof.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $V$ be a supspace of $(X,\tau)$ and $A\subseteq V$. Let $V$ be closed in $X$.
>
> Then $A$ is closed in $V$ if and only if $A$ is closed in $X$.

Where the subspace $V$ has the relative topology $\tau_V:=\{ U\cap V: U\in \tau\}$

Where do I use the fact that $V$ is closed in $X$ in the the  following proof.

#### Proof

$\Rightarrow$

If $A$ is closed in $V$ then $V\setminus A\in \tau_V$ and then $V\setminus A = U\cap V$ for a certain $U\in \tau$.

Now consider:

$$\begin{align}
X\setminus (V\setminus A) &= X\setminus (U\cap V)\\
(X\setminus V)\cup A &= (X\setminus U)\cup (X\setminus V)\\
A &=  X\setminus U
\end{align}$$

(Because $A\subseteq V$)

Since $U\in \tau, X\setminus U$ is closed in $X$ and so is $A$.

$\Leftarrow$

Since $A$ is closed in $X$, $X\setminus A\in \tau$.

Because $A\subseteq V$ then $(X\setminus A)\cap V = V\setminus A \in \tau_V$ or $A$ is closed in $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$(X\setminus V)\cup A=(X\setminus V)\cup (X\setminus U) $$
does not imply
$$A=(X\setminus U) $$

Example: Let $X=\mathbb R$, $A=V=[0,1)$, $U=\emptyset$.

Comment: Hmm, good point. So the proof is wrong. Any ideas to put me in the right direction?

Comment: @dietervdf: $X\setminus A=(V\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus V)=U\cup(X\setminus V)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, I see now. Final remark: in the proof part $\Leftarrow$ there is no usage of $V$ being closed in $X$ isn't it?

Comment: @dietervdf: That’s correct. If $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A\cap V$ is closed in $V$ for any $V\subseteq X$, even if $A$ isn’t a subset of $V$.